# Using $size of array in it's own document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm certain of how to do this when i'm actually working with the values in a form but i'm curious if it's possible to seed the database like this, obviously not my way because it's not working but it shows the idea

```
Order.find({}).remove()
        .then(() => {
          Order.create(
            {
              orderDate: new Date(),
              items: [
                {
                  itemname: 'Flex',
                  numOfOrdItems: 3,
                  numOfRecItems: 1
                },
                {
                  itemname: 'Flex13',
                  numOfOrdItems: 6,
                  numOfRecItems: 6
                }
              ],
              totalItems: {$size: '$items'}
            });
        });
```

where 'totalItems' would be evaluated as 2

Comment: Just declare items before Order.create and use items.length

Comment: MongoDB has "two" `$size` operators, but neither of them are for use in this context. There is `$size` for use in returning an "existing size" in an aggregation statement. There is also `$size` as a query operator to test for an fixed size. You seem confused on where to apply things. If it is not listed in ["Update Operators"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) and the method you are using does not end in `update()`, ( and `.create()` does not "end" like that ) then you do not use it at all.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks. I was aware that it wouldn't work in this specific context but I wasn't sure if there was another function I might be overlooking that would handle a case such as this. Although after thinking about iI think it it would just be a lazy approach anyways when the calculation can just be done before posting to the DB anyways.

Comment: Well that is what everyone does agree is the best approach. Such an operator would be useless unless comparing to an "existing" array. And presently there is not such an operator, since we also recommend you rather use `$inc` to "increment" such a field as you change array elements via `$push` or `$pull`.

Comment: ah, gotcha. I was not aware of that. thanks!